# Los objetos que representan elementos HTML, ¿Existen previamente o se crean apenas se llama a un metodo como querySelector() o querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Cuando se comienza a ejecutar el programa, ¿Todos los elementos HTML ya tienen su representación en el objeto `document`? o se crean cuando se llama a un método como

- `querySelector()`

o

- `getElementsById()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **DOM** como tal ya existe en cuanto la página es solicitada y el navegador lo interpreta y *pinta* en el viewport.

**CASO 1**

Partiendo de lo anterior lo puedes comprobar del siguiente modo:

Si tratas de acceder a una etiqueta HTML posterior a que esta fue renderizada por el navegador entonces existirá y aparecerá si mandas a imprimir el `document`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    <script>
        console.log(document)
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Nota: Busca la etiqueta **`h1`** dentro del resultado en el console y notarás su presencia.

**CASO 2**

Si por el contrario declaras el acceso al `document` al inicio del documento HTML donde esa etiqueta aún no existe entonces la impresión que obtengas en el `console` no arrojará el `h1`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <script>
        console.log(document)
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Nota: Aquí el h1 no sale impreso al momento de hacer el `console` por que el document al momento de ser requerido e impreso aún no conoce de la *existencia* de dicha etiqueta.

Por lo tanto aquí deberías:

- Declarar tus `scripts` al final de tu documento HTML
- Al momento en el que el `script` se lea dichas etiquetas HTML que requieras ya existirán renderizadas en el árbol del DOM
- En este punto evitas que la página ralentize su carga pues estás dejando la lógica de programación  y que ocupa mas *esfuerzo* al final y dejando: **HTML y CSS** al inicio.

Al final los métodos:

- `document.getElementById`
- `document.querySelector()`
- `document.querySelectorAll()`

Buscarán en primer instancia aquellos nodos que ya existen, en caso contrario que requieras acceder a nodos que serán declarados de forma dinámica entonces tal vez te conviene mas leer sobre: **Delegación de eventos**.

**EJEMPLO DEL CASO 2**

De hecho por ejemplo si tratas de obtener el `h1` y asignarlo a una variable para posteriormente imprimirlo asi:

```
  let tituloH1 = document.querySelector("h1")
    console.log(tituloH1.textContent)
```

Obtendrás como resultado:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Mientras que si mueves el script al final del HTML y repites la acción anterior por consola sale:

> "Hola Mundo"